# Show that if $W$ has a uniform distribution over $[0,\pi]$, $V=-\cos W$ has an $\arcsin(-1,1)$ distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've been struggling with the following problem for a few days, not really knowing where to start:

> Suppose $W$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,\pi]$ and $V = -\cos(W)$. Show that $V$ has an $\arcsin(-1,1)$ distribution.
>
> Hint: $\cos 2\alpha = 1-2\sin^2\alpha$

Apologies for the vagueness of the question but having no starting point kinda makes it hard to be specific.

Comment: For a start: can you spell out what exactly is meant here by '$\arcsin(-1,1)$ distribution'?

Comment: For $\arcsin(0,1)$; PDF: $f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$, CDF: $F(x) = \frac2\pi\arcsin\sqrt{x}$. To turn the $\arcsin(0,1)$ distribution in to an $\arcsin(a,b)$ distribution simply apply $Y = (b-a)X + a$ with $X$ a variable with the $\arcsin(0,1)$ distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cdf of [the arcsin($-1,1$) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution#Arbitrary_bounded_support) is

$$\frac2{\pi}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+1}2}\right)$$

on $[-1,1]$ and it is $0$ below $-1$ and it is $1$ above $1$.

Now, we have
$$P(V<x)=P(-\cos(W)<x)=P(\cos(W)>x)=P(W>\arccos(x))=1-\frac1{\pi}\arccos(x)$$
because $W$ is distributed uniformly over $[0,\pi]$, that is, because  $P(W>a)=1-\frac1{\pi}a$ if $0\leq a\leq\pi.$

The question is if

$$\frac2{\pi}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+1}2}\right)=1-\frac1{\pi}\arccos(x)?$$

The answer is yes! But this is a question of trigonometry.

Comment: Very clear explanation! Thanks!